# Lagrangian density for hydrodynamics from Lagrangian of discrete particles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, continuum-mechanics

It is one of the most famous examples [Goldstein "Classical mechanics" 3rd ed. pp. 558-561] to go from discrete chain of particles to continuous Lagrangian density by assuming that the discrete particles have their Lagrangian as

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_i \left( m \dot\eta_i^2 - k(\eta_{i+1}-\eta_i )^2\right).$$

In the last equation, $m$ is mass of the discrete particle, $k$ is spring constant and $\eta$ is a displacement from equilibrium.
Then by going to the continuous limit, you obtain Lagrangian density to be

$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \rho^2 \dot\eta^2 - Y \left( \frac{d\eta}{dx} \right)^2 \right).$$

Here, $\rho$ is mass density which for small widths $a$ is $\approx m/a$, $Y$ is constant which for small widths $a$ is $\approx ka$.

For hydrodynamics with negligible friction, we have the following Lagrangian density.

$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \rho_0^2 \dot{\vec{\eta}}^2 - f 
(\mathrm{div}(\vec{\eta})) \right) $$

Is there a particular intuitive discrete picture or model that has a Lagrangian which under specific continuous limit approaches given hydrodynamics Lagrangian density? Maybe there is some interpretation for the divergence of displacement vector? Also maybe function $f$ can be found from discrete potential (similar to $Y \approx ka$)?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491864/2451

Comment: Are you following a reference for the hydrodynamic model?

Comment: @Qmechanic no, I made it up. But it seems to give correct equations of motion.

Comment: Consider to include the correct equations of motion for clarity.